# How to train an ensemble model in parallel?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, parallel-processing

I want to train an ensemble model, consisting of 8 keras models. I want to train it in a closed loop, so that i can automatically add/remove training data, when the training is finished, and then restart the training. I have a machine with 8 GPUs and want to put one model on each GPU and train them in parallel with the same data. All distributed strategies just do model cloning, but i just want to run model.fit() in parallel 8 times, with 8 different models.
Ideally i would have 8 threads, that each call model.fit(), but i cannot find something similar. I could also split the training into 8 completely different scripts, that run in parallel, but than i would still need an automated way to start and finish training, and check when the training is finished, so i can update my dataset and restart the training.

A hacky way to achieve this is to call the different scripts with
'os.system('python training_script_1.py')'
but that just seems ugly and it is harder than necessary to update the training data. (I would need to write a file to disk, and load it everytime i call a script this way).
Isn't there a a better way to handle closed loop training of multiple keras models?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this block:

```
st_1 = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(["GPU:0", "GPU:1"])
with st_1.scope():
model[0].fit()

st_2 = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy("GPU:2")
with st_2.scope():
model[1].fit()
```

Comment: This doesnt train in parallel though, does it? It trains first model[0] on 2 GPUs, and after that training is finished, it traines model 1 on the gpu:2